# Yii2: как установить атрибут «checked» для радиокнопки, генерируемой «ActiveForm::radio()»

Tags: yii2

Как установить атрибут `checked` для радиокнопки, генерируемой `ActiveForm::radio()`:

```
echo $form->field( $model, 'radioButton' )->radio( [

    'checked' => 'checked', // or "'checked' => true" don't work

] );
```

В документации по методу [`ActiveForm::radio()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#radio()-detail) сказано:

> ... The rest of the options will be rendered as the attributes of the resulting tag. ...

---

Может это тянется из-за неправильного использования мной данного метода, так как я так и не понял что значит следующее:

> This method will generate the "checked" tag attribute according to the model attribute value.
>
> Этот метод будет генерировать атрибут «checked» в соответствии со значением атрибута модели.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Отвечаю сразу сам, так как пока писал — понял.

---

Всё дело в невнимательном прочтении сказанного в документации ...

> Этот метод будет генерировать атрибут «checked» **в соответствии со *значением атрибута модели***.

То есть, атрибут `checked` устанавливается автоматически в соответствии со значением атрибута модели (если значение атрибута модели совпадает со значение текущей радиокнопки, то ей устанавливается атрибут `checked`):

```
// По умолчанию у невыбранной радиокнопки значение 0,
// а у выбранной — 1.

$model->radioButton = '1';

echo $form->field( $model, 'radioButton' )->radio();
```

---

Это же касается и [`radioList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#radioList()-detail):

```
// ... The selection of the radio buttons is taken from the value of the model
// attribute.

$model->radioButton = 'second';

echo $form->field( $model, 'radioButton' )

    ->radioList( [

        // <value> => <label>

        'first' => 'Первый',

        'second' => 'Второй', // Selected item

    ] );
```